# Explanation of $\overset{R}{\leftarrow}$ notation

Tags: notation

I have an elliptic curve $E\backslash \mathbb{F}_p $ (for $p$ prime) which has a point $P$ of order $n$

I need to choose an integer $s\overset{R}{\leftarrow}[1,n]$

Am I right in saying that $s$ should be a random number in the range $[1,n]$? If not, could someone set me straight please.

Comment: Same question indeed http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131655/explanation-of-left-cdot-right-notation a mathematical notation is always explained by the context

Comment: That question was also asked by me. I was just asking if I had understood the notation correctly as I have never seen it before

Comment: Next time ask it in your other question, this question alone is "missing context"

Comment: All I'm asking for is clarification of the meaning of $\overset{R}{\leftarrow}$ - this is as much context as I have to work with